# Put the upload list from a Upload Ant into a different page

Tags: javascript, antd

I would like to ask that is that possible for us to put the upload list from an upload ant component to a new section such as new `<span>` or `<div>` to display the upload list on another page. Below are my codes

```
<div>
    <Upload
        ref="upload"
        type="file"
        :show-upload-list="true"
        :before-upload="handleUpload"
        :data="uploadFile"
        :headers="header"
        :on-success="uploadSuccess"
        :action="fileUrl"
        :on-remove="removeFile"
        :accept="accept"
        :default-file-list="defaultList"
        :on-error="uploadFail"
        id="uploadLocation"
        :multiple="true"
        :percent="number"
        :name="testingUpload"
        @change="testingUpload"
    >
        <Button            
            style="width: 150px"
            icon="ios-cloud-upload-outline"
        >Choose File</Button>
    </Upload>
    <span id="uploadListSpan"></span>
</div>
```